# What kind of data is it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

maybe my question can seem very silly, but i am a beginner and i am doing an exercise from a book about MVC and ASP.NET.
I don't understand the meaning of the second rows:

```
[LargerThanValidationAttribute(18)]
public VoterAge { get; set; }
```

because i see that VolterAge has not a type, and i read the message from VS that VolterAge doesn't exist in this context, and i don't understand the meaning of it. What have i to use for VolterAge? A field in a DataBase? What type of data is it?

Thank you to all.

P.S. LargerThanValidationAttribute is an extension of ValidationAttribute.

Comment: `Voter`, not `Volter`... note the lack of an `L`...

Comment: This won't even compile?!

Comment: you misread or its misprint

Comment: Ok, do you mean it always needs a type?

Comment: The second line is not valid C# - it should have a type, e.g. `public int VoterAge { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely missing a type in that property declaration.

At a guess, given it's 'VoterAge' and by the value supplied in the `LargerThanValidationAttribute` I would say it's missing `int`

It should be

```
[LargerThanValidationAttribute(18)]
public int VoterAge { get; set; }
```

This declares that property to be of type `int`